# Access variable in Shared Sub

Tags: vb.net

is there a way to access a variable in Form_Load from an event handler?

Please dont mind the code, this is just a representation of my question.

```
Public Class Form

Public Sub Form_Load()
Dim x as string
x = MyClass.MethodGetValue()
End Sub

Private Shared Sub OnChanged()
MyClass2.MethodGetValue(x)
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: as long as `x` is declared at the form level, you should be fine... *thats* why code *does* matter

Comment: yeah, sorry I forgot to put in the declaration there. Edited the question. I've tried declaring it at form level, however, it gives me a "Cannot refer to an instance member of a class from within a shared method" error.

Comment: I think this solved the problem, I declared the variable in form level as shared. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It's about the scope of the variable. In your situation you need a class variable. This allows it to be used anywhere inside of this class.

```
Public Class Form1 
  Private x As Object 'pick the datatype that matches your needs
  Public Sub Form_Load()
    x = MyClass.MethodGetValue()
  End Sub

  Private Sub OnChanged() 
    MyClass2.MethodGetValue(x)
  End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: tried this, it gives me a "Cannot refer to an instance member of a class from within a shared method" error

Comment: Right, change the sub to this. That is a protective measure since a shared method's class does not have to be initialized and that variable would be null.